# Symfony2 - Can you submit post data with redirect?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to submit some data in post method when redirecting to another page. The solution coming in my mind is-

1. Create a form with post values and use javascript redirect. [depend on js enable]
2. sending data using curl and the do something like header redirect [depend on curl enable]

Is there any other method to do it or something native to Symfony2? Like for example when using redirect method in Symfony can I send some data in post method along it?

Comment: You're going to use a combination of [Symfony Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) and [Redirecting](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#redirecting). When you use `generateUrl` you can pass values through [route placeholders](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#routing-with-placeholders). If you're using a framework, you should utilize the tools that the framework makes available to you. Good luck!

Comment: @sjagar I was looking in redirect method. Can I pass some value[in post] with it? So far in my undersanding redirect take only two parameter-first generate url, second says whether if its 301/302 etc. But not sure how to declare post values with it..

Comment: Why do you need `POST`? There a dozen other ways to pass data within Symfony without reinventing the wheel. Namely route placeholders which I linked above for you.

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you use sessions to store values before redirecting, this will be much easier

```
// Set a session value
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
$session->set('session name', 'session value');

// redirect
$this->redirect('redirect to somewhere');
```

get the session value after redirecting

```
 $value = $session->get('session name');
```